# Azure : Resource usage API issue

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I tried to pull the Azure resource usage data for billing metrics. I followed the steps as mentioned in the blog to get Usage data of resources.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219001.aspx

Even If I set "start and endtime"  parameter in the URL, its not take effect. It returns entire output [ from resource created/added time ].

For example :
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedStartTime=2017-03-03T00%3a00%3a00%2b00%3a00&reportedEndTime=2017-03-04T00%3a00%3a00%2b00%3a00&aggregationGranularity=Hourly&showDetails=true"

As per the above URL, it should return the data between "2017-03-03 to 2017-03-04". But It shows the data from 2nd March [ 2017-03-02]. don't know why this return entire output and time filter section is not working.

Note : Endtime parameter value takes effect, mean it shows the output upto what mentioned in the endtime. But it doesn't consider the start time.

Anyone have a suggestion on this.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the resources are created on 2nd of March?

Comment: @GauravMantri, yes. You are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few things to consider:

- There is `usage date/time` and then there is `reported date/time`.
  Former tells you the date/time when the resources were used while the
  latter tells you the date/time when this information was received by
  the billing sub-system. There will be some delay in when the
  resources used versus when they are reported. From this [`link`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219001.aspx):

> Set {dateTimeOffset-value} for reportedStartTime and reportedEndTime
>   to valid dateTime values. Please note that this dateTimeOffset value
>   represents the timestamp at which the resource usage was recorded
>   within the Azure billing system. **As Azure is a distributed system,
>   spanning across 19 datacenters around the world, there is bound to be
>   a delay between the resource usage time (when the resource was
>   actually consumed) and the resource usage reported time (when the
>   usage event reached the billing system)** and callers need a predictable
>   way to get all usage events for a subscription for a given time
>   period.

- The query only lets you search for reported date/time and there is no provision for usage date/time. However the data returned back to you contains usage date/time and not the reported date/time.

Long story short, because of the delay in propagating the usage information to the billing sub-system, the behavior you're seeing is correct. In my experience, it takes about 24 hours for all the usage information to show up in the billing sub-system.

The way we handle this scenario in our application is we fetch the data for a longer duration and then pick up only the data we're interested in seeing. So for example, if I need to see the data for 1st of March then we query the data for reported date/time from 1st March to say 4th March (i.e. today's date) and then discard any data where usage date is not 1st of March.

If we don't find any data (which is quite possible and is happening in your case as well), we simply tell the users that usage information is not yet available.

Comment: thanks for your update. let me follow this way. One more thing, pls upvote my question, if its a correct one. thx

Comment: I tried to use partnercenter api to get the billing details. But API call return 401 error code. the details provided on partnercpi are correct one and its working fine If I give it as input for Subscription API. URL  : "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers/<Customer-tenant-ID>/subscriptions/<Subscription-ID>/usagerecords/resources". Can you suggest what can be the reason for the error.

Comment: I would recommend asking this as a separate question instead of putting here as a comment. Please provide all details there (including code). Thanks!

Comment: sorry for that, I created separate question over there "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43134131/partner-center-rest-api-401-error". Please share your suggestion