# Partner Center rest api 401 error

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I tried to use partnercenter api to get the billing details. But API call return 401 error code. the details provided on partnercpi are correct one and its working fine If I give it as input for Subscription API.

URL :  `https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers/<Customer-tenant-ID>/subscriptions/<Subscription-ID>/usagerecords/resources`

Can you suggest what can be the reason for the error.

Reference link : https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/01/05/azure-resource-manager-authentication-with-python/

Here is my python code.

```
import adal
import requests


application_secret = 'asdq23Y+tRgEspFxQDPasd'
application_id = '523129-1267b-123'


authentication_endpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'
resource  = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authentication_endpoint + tenant_id)
token_response = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource, application_id, application_secret)

access_token = token_response.get('accessToken')


endpoint = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers/<customer tenant ID>/subscriptions/<sub-id>/usagerecords/resources"


headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token}

json_output = requests.get(endpoint,headers=headers)
print json_output
```

Output Response:

```
<Response [401]>
```

Is this method not fit for partnerapi usage collection ?. If not pls suggest alternate option. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @gaurav-mantri, Do you've any idea why its return 401 unauthorised access?

Answer (score 1):

401 is because partner center does not work with just the token from Azure AD.

The actual Auth workflow

1. Get a Token from Azure AD.
2. Use that token to get an access token from PartnerCenter.
3. Use this token to communicate with the partner center REST APIs.

More Info [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/mt634709.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your reply. do you have any sample code ?. Kindly share it to me if possible.

Comment: The link i provided above has a sample done using C# to decipher.

Comment: I don't see where on the linked documentation that you need to do #2 (Get another access token from Partner Center)